# I am trying to assign a group to my users with a form on registration but getting this error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

AttributeError at /register_user
'User' object has no attribute 'group'

I already have the attribute group

```
class register_form(UserCreationForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                   required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'group']
```

this is my view

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='system_administrator').exists())
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            my_group = form.instance.group
            my_group.user_set(user)
            return redirect('index.html')
    else:
        form = register_form
    return render(request, 'register_user.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is what the post request looks like (it has other attributes as well obviously)

```
first_name  
'asdfadsf'
last_name   
'asdfasdf'
email   
'asdfasdf@asdfasdf.com'
group   
'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it by replacing

```
 my_group = form.instance.group
```

with:

```
my_group = form.data['group']
```